# Unsatisfied Link Error for library when running Spring application inside Docker container

Tags: java, docker, shared-libraries

I have created a working back-end application, but I want to Dockerize it now. The back-end uses the nauty library and everything works fine when not using Docker containers.

To make this work, locally I had to start the application using `java -Djava.library.path="<PATH>/backend/lib/" -jar backend.jar`. The library path points to the directory where the nauty library (libnauty.so) resides. In my ~/.bashrc, I had to set the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<PATH>/backend/lib/:/usr/local/lib`. After doing this, the application works fine.

After dockerizing the application, this gives problems. I get the error `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no nauty in java.library.path: "/home/backend/lib/"`.

I tried solving the issue by setting the environment variable in the docker container and using the same entrypoint for the application, but the issue remains.

My Dockerfile for the back-end looks like this.

```
FROM openjdk:17-oracle
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/backend/lib/:/usr/local/lib
COPY ${JAR_FILE} /home/backend/backend.jar
COPY . /home/backend
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.library.path=\"/home/backend/lib/\"", "-jar", "/home/backend/backend.jar"]
```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to copy those native library files into Docker image and use the path inside of the image to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

Comment: @AlexCheng
Yeah, so the .so library is inside the /home/backend/lib container, which is copied along with the rest of the files. Do I need to change the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to something else?

Comment: You don't have to. Just make sure `LD_LIBRARY_PATH ` refers to the correct path in the container.

Comment: @AlexCheng 
Yeah I think that is the case, It points to the /home/backend/lib/ directory and inside that dictory is the libnauty.so